# Better method to use in large application

Tags: java, string

I am trying to extract values from  EnumValues using set bit of a given binary String.Say if we have string as `1000000(64)` output should be `VAL7`.
I have two method to do this

1.To have one extra index j
2.use `stringBuilder.reverse()` method

From both I am getting correct output but not sure which one is better in terms of
1.Speed
2.Readable and should be used in large application

```
public class test3 {
        public enum EnumValues {
            VAL1,
            VAL2,
            VAL3,
            VAL4,
            VAL5,
            VAL6,
            VAL7,
            VAL8,
            VAL9,
            VAL10
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String stringBit = Long.toBinaryString(1020);//give long input here
                System.out.println("stringBit : " +stringBit );
                //First method
                int len = stringBit.length();
                int j=0;//enum index
                for(int i=len-1; i>=0; i--,j++){
                    if(stringBit.charAt(i) == '1'){
                        String output = EnumValues.values()[j].toString();//final value
                        System.out.println("val1..."+output);
                    }
                }

            //second method
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.append(stringBit);
            str.reverse();
            System.out.println("val...."+str);
            int len2 = str.length();
            for(int i=0;i<len2;i++){
                if(str.charAt(i) == '1'){
                    String output = EnumValues.values()[i].toString();
                    System.out.println("out2....." +output);

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is particularly great because it's a lot of code. Maybe try:

```
BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { 1020 });
for (int i = bitSet.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bitSet.nextSetBit(i + 1)) {
    System.out.println(EnumValues.values()[i]);
}
```

Or when you're interested in the lowest overhead:

```
long longValue = 1020;
for (int i = 0; longValue != 0; longValue >>>= 1, i++) {
    if (longValue % 2 == 1)
        System.out.println(EnumValues.values()[i]);
}
```

should be allocation-free.

Comment: In the second method allocation-free refer to not using another variable?

Comment: it's not creating any (`String`, `StringBuilder`, `BitSet`, `long[]`-array, ...) objects,